# alter statements failing on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm new to Oracle (have a SQL Server background). I'm trying to execute this anonymous block but it is failing with ORA-06550. I feel like that I may not understand what can be done and not done in an anonymous block.  If someone would be so kind to educate me, I'd appreciate it.

```
BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_1_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
     ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_2_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
     ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_3_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
END;
```

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
>      raise return select update while with 
>        <<
>      continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>      savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>      json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
>
> The symbol "lock was inserted before "ALTER" to continue.
>
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 49:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
>
> , in
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: You can't run DDL statements in PL/SQL

Comment: Of course you can, @a_horse, using dynamic SQL (execute immediate).

Answer (score 1):

If it, for some reason, has to be PL/SQL, you'd need to execute is as *dynamic SQL*, using `execute immediate`. For example:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 FNAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)     --> 10
 LNAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate 'alter table test modify fname varchar2(20)';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 FNAME                                              VARCHAR2(20)     --> 20
 LNAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a `DDL` statement inside a PL/SQL block. Remove the `BEGIN-END` statements, and execute the alter statements in plain `SQL`:

```
ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_1_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_2_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_3_NAME> MODIFY <FIELD_NAME> VARCHAR2(50);
```

As a best practice, you should avoid `PL/SQL` for DDL statements. PL/SQL is a procedural language, while you don't regularly **create/drop/modify objects** on the fly. There could be specific scenarios where you might have to do it in PL/SQL as scripts, you could use `dynamic SQL` inside a PL/SQL block as suggested by @Littlefoot.